# define hover style from id or class

Tags: css, hyperlink, stylesheet

if i have something like

```
<a id="link-id">...</a>
```

or

```
<a class="link-class">...</a>
```

how can I setup the hover behavior using link-id or link-class? I've tried link-id:hover and link-class:hover but it does not work.

Comment: #link-id:hover  or .link-class:hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-class like this:

```
#link-id{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    transition:0.5s ease;
}

#link-id:hover{    /*or .link-class if targeting by class*/
    font-size:30px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:poitner;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/bD5kM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write # before id of element, and . before class name.
For example:

```
.link-class:hover {}

#link-id:hover {}
```